# Comparing Google Analytics clicks between two sites

Tags: google-analytics

I am tracking outbound links on a certain site, say Site1, using Google Analytics and its [events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7478520?hl=en). It seems to work alright, the clicks are recorded on all the outbound links and everything is fine for now.

But then I have another site (Site2) that also uses Google Analytics. Now I add a link on Site1 pointing to Site2 and wait for it to get some clicks. After this, if I check the Site1's GA stats for clicks on this particular link, I might see a number that is far bigger than what I see if I check the Site2's GA stats for how many visitors have come to the site from Site1.

So this is a situation where e.g. 5000 unique users have clicked the link on Site1 (pointing to Site2), but only e.g. 3000 users have come to Site2 from Site1. Why is this?

Could it be that some of the users have clicked the link but closed the new tab before the page was actually loaded (=click is counted but the page load is not), or is another possibility?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is an age old issue. this article applies to your situation too: https://www.receptional.com/click-vs-visits-why-the-discrepancy/

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, if i say click on the link to Site2 from Site1 but later i access Site1 from any other medium i ll be seen as i came from that last medium and not from Site1. This has to do with [attribution models](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1662518?hl=en).